# Get array's values base on a second array's keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's take two arrays:

```
$aliases = array(
    'id'   => 'real_id',
    'date' => 'real_date',
    'name' => 'real_name'
);
$data = array(
    'id'   => 1,
    'name' => 'Lorem ipsum'
);
```

I would like to retrieve every `$aliases` value for keys defined in `$data` array (no need to check if the key exists, I already did it at this point using `array_intersect_key()`). Here is the expected result:

```
array('real_id', 'real_name');
```

Currently, I'm able to do it using a `foreach`:

```
$realkeys = array();
foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
    $realkeys[] = $aliases[$key];
}
```

But is there any native PHP function to do it in a more smartly way?

Comment: there is, you've already used it `array_intersect_key`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP's `array_intersect_key` like this:

```
    <?php
        $aliases = array(
                'id'   => 'real_id',
                'date' => 'real_date',
                'name' => 'real_name'
        );
        $data = array(
                'id'   => 1,
                'name' => 'Lorem ipsum'
        );

        print_r(array_values(array_intersect_key($aliases, $data)));
    ?>
```

> Array ( [0] => real_id [1] => real_name )